# How do I change the Fontweight of Table Titles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fonts

Upon creating a table, the 'VariablesNames' at the top of each column are automatically bolded.  When I check the table in my diary file, each of the column names are surrounded by HTML style strong tags.  Is there a line of code I can use to prevent the automatic bolding?

<strike>I've had no luck with the MATLAB documentation for fontweights in regards to table titles: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.table-properties.html  They mention font weights, but they don't provide an example of how to implement the code.</strike>  (The strike-through text wasn't relevant documentation for console outputs.)

Here is the command I'm using to create a table: X = array2table(B,'VariableNames', {'y','One','Two','Three'}); The column titles come out bold, for some reason. Worth noting that B is a 5x4 matrix.

Comment: `t.FontWeight = 'bold'` is an example implementation. However, that will set the content to bold font, but column names not touched. In fact if I run the example code in the link, the table title is normal font. Also, what do you mean by "surrounded by tags"? What tag?

Comment: I think it is the hard-coded way of the function's command window output. I don't think you have a choice. You could edit the diary file afterwards, though. You could also write your own implementation of printing the table. The reference is for GUI stuff, not the command window.

Comment: Use regular expression.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are mixing things up: the documentation page that you referenced refers to tables displayed in Matlab GUI (using the `uitable` function), and its FontWeight property refers to the font-weight of the internal data elements displayed in that table.

This is apparently entirely unrelated to what you're actually doing, which is to use a non-GUI data table, such as one that is created using the `table` function. Such a table is an object which uses an internal overload of the `disp` function in order to display the table contents in the Matlab console (Command Window). This overloaded `disp` function displays the table headers using the HTML <Strong> tag. You can see the full source code in *matlabroot/toolbox/matlab/datatypes/@tabular/disp.m*, and the part that adds the strong tag around line 45.

In short, if you want table output not to use a strong tag in its header, you need to either modify that file, or create your own class that inherits the <s>`table`</s> `tablular` class and overloads the `disp` function in whatever way that you wish.

**Addendum**: I just discovered an even simpler way:

```
feature('HotLinks',0);  % temporarily disable bolded headers (matlab.internal.display.isHot=false)
disp(myTable)
feature('HotLinks',1);  % restore the standard behavior (matlab.internal.display.isHot=true)
```

Comment: Hi Yair: inheriting from `table` won't work as `table` is Sealed. But there's a little undocumented feature of the `disp` method of `table` that may help here - see my answer. Not sure it's a big enough deal to deserve post on its own, but you're welcome to blog it if you like...you could mention the use of `matlab.internal.display.isHot` too, which can occasionally be useful.

Comment: Thanks Sam. When I wrote my answer I couldn't find a way to modify the internal Hot feature (there is no corresponding setHot() method, nor corresponding m- or p-code), but I just took the challenge and found out after some digging that there's a corresponding `feature('HotLinks')` that does the trick, so I just updated my answer

Comment: Adding `feature('HotLinks',0);` to my function did the trick.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> In short, if you want table output not to use a strong tag in its
>   header, you need to either modify that file, or create your own class
>   that inherits the table class and overloads the disp function in
>   whatever way that you wish.

Unfortunately the table class is sealed, therefore a subclass cannot inherit from it.

```
Error using unbold_table
Class 'table' is Sealed and may not be used as a superclass.
```

You could always go into the source code as Yair suggested and edit it.

Answer (score 2):

As @YairAltman mentions, the bolding is done by the `disp` method of the `table` class.

(Actually, that's not quite true: in older versions, it's done by the `disp` method of the `table` class, in the more recent versions, it's done by the `disp` method of the `tabular` superclass of the `table` class).

Yair suggests two ideas:

Firstly, that you might be able to create your own class that inherits from `table`, and implement your own version of `disp`. Unfortunately, that won't work as `table` is Sealed, so you can't inherit from it. (Of course, if you're comfortable with modifying the MATLAB source code you could unseal it; but I don't recommend trying that, they've sealed it for very good reasons).

Secondly, that you might be able to modify the source code for the `disp` method so that it doesn't do the bolding. That would work, but you might not want to fiddle around with the MATLAB source code (and some may have it installed by IT in a way that is read-only anyway).

However, there is a little undocumented feature of the `disp` method of `table`/`tabular`, that may help you here without modifying anything: if you pass in an additional argument to `disp`, you can turn off the bold.

```
>> a = table(1,2);
>> disp(a) % the following Var1 and Var2 are bold
    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____
    1       2   
>> disp(a,false) % the following Var1 and Var2 are not bold
    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____
    1       2
```

The default value for the second argument is `true`, so to achieve this you need to call `disp` explicitly with the second argument `false`.